# Determine position on ImageView

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, bitmap

I'm developing a mobile application (xamarin.android & c#). Situation is showing an image having a certain width, e.g. 2380 pixel. I'm using the "ShowPress"-gesture so that the user is able to mark s a point on the picture. Now I need the location on the picture.

The event gets a parameter that provides the values RawX as well as RawY relating to the screen. How can I get the size of the ImageView? I need it to determine the position on original bitmap.

```
    public void OnShowPress(MotionEvent e)
    {
        var x = e.RawX;
        var y = e.RawY;
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Do you need the size of your imageview?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could read this document : [MotionEvent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html),

Position [e.RawX/e.RawY](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#getRawX()) is related to the screen :

> Returns the original raw X coordinate of this event. For touch events on the screen, this is the original location of the event on the screen, before it had been adjusted for the containing window and views.

Position e.GetX/e.GetY is related to the  view :

> getX(int) for the first pointer index (may be an arbitrary pointer identifier).

### Better understanding :

- **`RawX/RawY` that is guaranteed to return absolute coordinates, relative to the device screen**.
- **While `GetX()/GetY()`, should return you coordinates, relative to the View, that dispatched them.**

So you could use `e.GetX()/e.GetY()` to determine the position on your original bitmap.